# Homology of the product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have to prove that

$$H_q(X\times\partial I^n,X\times\{p_0\})=H_{q-n}(X)$$

for $X$ a topological space.

I tried using induction, but I didn't go too far, and think that using some exact sequence like Mayer-Vietoris is not gonna be too helpful, now I am trying to prove it by the definition of the singular homology groups and the simplex, but if someone has another idea that could help me that would be great.

Comment: Do you know Kunneth formula?

Comment: No, i don´t know Kunneth formula

Comment: That's _the way_ to compute (co)homology of products. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem

Comment: Yeah i read, but i didn´t see that result and using that is too easy (also the only way that i could do it until now) but the idea was that the problem should be solvable without using that result

Comment: Do you know how to do the case where $X$ is a point? You might be able to generalise it.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz the case when X is a point is easy but i don´t see how to generalize it

Comment: could you maybe break the sphere into hemispheres $S_1$ $S_2$ and induct on dimension using mayer vietoris with the two sets $X\times S_1$ $X\times S_2$?

Comment: Can i use Mayer Vietoris with relative homology?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another hint since you cannot use Kunneth: Replace the pair $(X\times \partial I^n, X\times p)$ with the pair $(X\times I^n, X\times \partial (I^n))$ (homology does not change, by excision: That would be your task to see how excision is used here). Now, use the long exact sequence for the pair; I  guess, you already covered this one in your class.

Comment: I will think about how you use excision there, but i don´t see how the exact long sequence is gonna help there, because i should know$H_q(X\times \partial (I^n))$ and $H_q(X\times (I^n))$ or i am missing something?